# class name as argument in a public function

Tags: php, class, oop, laravel, laravel-4

What's the difference between:

```
class PostController extends \BaseController {
      public function delete($id) {
        $deletePost = Post::findOrFail($id);
        return View::make('backend.delete')->with('post', $deletePost);
      }
}
```

and

```
class PostController extends \BaseController {
      public function delete(Post $post) {
        return View::make('backend.delete')->with('post', $post);
      }
}
```

Can somebody explain to me: `public function delete(Post $post)`

we are taking a Class named "Post" as a variable `$post`?

**UPDATE1.**

in routes.php:

```
Route::model('post', 'Post');

Route::get('delete/{post}', array('uses' => 'PostController@delete'));
Route::post('delete', array('uses' => 'PostController@doDelete'));
```

and in PostController.php:

```
public function delete(Post $post) {
    return View::make('backend.delete')->with('post', $post);
}

public function doDelete() {
    $post = Post::findOrFail(Input::get('id'));
    $post->delete();

    return Redirect::action('PostController@home');
}
```

but anyway i get an error: No query results for model [Post]. 
with the 2nd method.

Comment: No, the argument passed as $post must be an object instance of type `Post`, or of a class that extends `Post`

Comment: http://docs.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.typehinting.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's just a type hinting:

> "Type hinting means that whatever you pass must be an instance of (the
>   same type as) the type you're hinting."

In your example it's Post:

```
public function delete(Post $post) { /* code */ }
```

It's just checks `$post` variable whether instance it or not. So everything looks good in your code. And it should work.

Answer (score 2):

They both achieve the same thing of giving you the model (if it exists).

The second way is called [Route Model binding](http://laravel.com/docs/routing#route-model-binding). Route model binding provides a convenient way to inject model instances into your routes.

To bind a model to a route:

```
Route::model('post', 'Post');
```

Next, define a route that contains a {user} parameter:

```
Route::get('delete/{post}', array('uses' => PostController@delete));
```

So we have bound the `{post}` parameter to the Post model, a Post instance will be injected into the route.

This means if someone reaches your delete() function - they have already provided a valid Post model - which is the equivalent of `Post::findOrFail($id)`

Comment: Thanks, i have update my questions, please take a look